# How to convert integer to string (function)?

Tags: c, function

I need help with this code, if anyone had a similar problem it would help me.

It is necessary to modify the following code, so that by entering integer values ​​in the form function, it prints that integer value as a string.

For example:

```
s = form(3,123, 456, 789);
```

They need to print: `123456789`.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

char* form(int n,...)
{
    char *result = 0, *next;
    int i;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int len = result ? strlen(result) : 0;
        next = va_arg(args, char *);
        char *tmp = (char *)malloc(len + strlen(next) + 1);

        strcpy(tmp, result ? result : "");
        strcat(tmp, next);
        free(result);
        result = tmp;
    }
    va_end(args);
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *s;
    s = form(3,123, 456, 789);
    printf("%s", s);
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in Advance! Best regards!

Comment: Use `sprintf()` to convert an integer to a string.

Comment: The arguments to the function are `int`, why are you using `char *next`?

Comment: This is stated in the code in which the appropriate modification is to be made.

Comment: Using `char*` instead of `int*` doesn't convert the integer to a string, it just results in undefined behavior when treated as a string.

Comment: What is the motivation on using vargs?

Comment: @PCSafe So this is the code before you've made the required changes? You need to post your attempted solution, not the original code.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to *print* and not *store*, it's much simpler to do it directly to `stdout` without any allocation. This is well-documented in the [c faq](http://c-faq.com/varargs/varargs1.html).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void form(unsigned n, ...) {
    va_list argp;
    va_start(argp, n);
    while(n) n--, printf("%d", va_arg(argp, int));
    va_end(argp);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
    form(3, 123, 456, 789);
    return 0;
}
```

If you intend to store and `malloc` the result, you may find it easier to count the characters needed in one loop around `va_arg` with `snprintf` using 0 as `n`, allocate, and then fill it on another loop.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define SZ 32
char* form(int n,...)
{
  char *result = calloc(1,1);
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, n);
  while(n --> 0)
  {
    int number = va_arg(args, int);
    char txt[SZ] = {0};
    char* c = txt+SZ-2;
    for(;number; --c,  number /= 10)
    {
        *c = number%10 + '0';
    }
    c++;
    result = strcat(realloc(result, strlen(result)+strlen(c)+1), c);
  }
  va_end(args);
  return result; // Caller MUST free
}


int main()
{
  char *s = form(3,123, 456, 7890);
  printf("%s", s);
  free(s);
  return 0;
}
```

This is inefficient because it repeatedly calls both `realloc` and `strlen`.
It might also be hard to follow because it fills a buffer backwards.
But I believe it works.

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

char* form(int n, ...)
{
    char *result = malloc(n * 11 + 1); // int is at most 11 characters long.
    char *position = result;

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int next = va_arg(args, int);
        sprintf(position, "%i", next);
        position += strlen(position);
    }

    va_end(args);
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    char *s = form(3, 123, 456, 789);
    printf("%s", s);
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Obvious problems:

1. Your intended input is "int", but you treated them as "char*"

```
    next = va_arg(args, char *);
    char *tmp = (char *)malloc(len + strlen(next) + 1);
```

2. Your first input should be treated as a "length"

See my quick fix.

Disclamer: I only have tested a few cases.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int decimal_len(int in) {
  int max_len_dec_int = 1000000000;
  int len = 10;
  while (len > 1) {
    if (in >= max_len_dec_int) {
      break;
    }
    max_len_dec_int /= 10;
    len--;
  }
  return len;
}

char *form(int n, ...) {
  char *result = 0;
  int next;
  int i;
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, n);

  if (n < 2) {
    printf("invalid parameter\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int len = result ? strlen(result) : 0;
    next = va_arg(args, int);
    char *new_str = (char *)malloc(decimal_len(next) + 1);
    sprintf(new_str, "%d", next);
    char *tmp = (char *)malloc(len + decimal_len(next) + 1);
    strcpy(tmp, result ? result : "");
    strcat(tmp, new_str);
    result = tmp;
  }
  va_end(args);
  return result;
}

int main() {
  {
    char *s;
    s = form(3, 123, 456, 789);
    printf("%s", s);
    free(s);
  }
  printf("\nAnother test\n");
  {
    char *s;
    s = form(4, 123, 456, 789, 123);
    printf("%s", s);
    free(s);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `decimal_len` is trying to do the work of `sprintf(new_str, "%d", next);` to pre-determine the length.  Could use `string_length = snprintf(0, 0, "%d", next);` to find the length and be confident you have the same length as in the next `sprintf(new_str, "%d", next);`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes, both get the same output and similar performance. The snprintf solution is much simpler.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica By the way, I made a simple benchmark and found my simple solution is much faster than the snprintf one(~30X). Although I guess it is would rarely worth the optimization in practice.

Answer (score 0):

`va_arg(args, char *);` makes more sense as `va_arg(args, int);` if the arguments are `int`.

Simplification:

1. Allocate once to the worst case needs.
2. Convert each `int` into a string with `sprintf()`.  Avoid all the unneeded `strlen(), strcat(), strcpy()` calls by using the return value of `sprintf()` to keep track of where to print.  Avoid a [slow alogirthm](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/schlemiel_the_painter%27s_algorithm).
3. Rights-size the buffer.
4. Be sure to `free()` when done.

---

Sample code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

// With 32-bit int, INT_MIN uses 11 characters.
#define INT_STR_LEN ((size_t)11)

char* form(unsigned n, ...) {
  // Determine worst case need.
  size_t sz = n * INT_STR_LEN + 1;
  char *s = malloc(sz);
  if (s) {
    char *end = s;  // Keep track of the end of the string.
    *end = '\0';    // In case n == 0
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, n);
    // Convert each argument to a string
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      int len = sprintf(end, "%d", va_arg(args, int)); // Print at the end
      if (len >= 0) {
        end += len; // Update length
      }
    }
    va_end(args);
    // Right size allocation
    sz = (size_t) (end - s) + 1;
    void *t = realloc(s, sz);
    if (t) {
      s = t;
    }
  }
  return s;
}

int main() {
  char *s;
  s = form(3, 123, 456, 789);
  printf("%s\n", s);
  free(s);
  return 0;
}
```